# Knockout JS refactoring

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockoutjs and I am not a JS guru either. I am banging my head on wall with this code and I need someone to help me refactor and make it DRY.

HTML Razor ASP.NET MVC

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control",@data_bind = "value: zip, event:{ keyup: $root.getCity, keydown: $root.inputnumeric}" })

ViewModel(options) {}
    self.inputnumeric= function (data, event) {

            var key = event.keyCode;
            if (!((key == 8) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        self.getCity = function (data, event) {
            var target = event.target;
            var value = target.value;
            var data = {
                zipCode: value
            }
            if (value.length < 4) {
                $(target).removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
            } else if (value.length > 4) {
                $(target).addClass('error').removeClass('valid');
            } else if ((value.length == 4)) {

                $.getJSON(self.options.cityapiurl, data, function (result) {

                    if (result.success) {
                        self.city(result.cityName);


                        $('#City').addClass('valid').removeClass('error');
                        $(target).addClass('valid').removeClass('error');

                    } else {
                        $(target).addClass('error').removeClass('valid');
                        $('#City').addClass('error').removeClass('valid');

                    }

                })
                  .error(function () { alert("error hapens"); });

            }
        };
```

Now i have this on a viewmodel.js.

But I also have almost the same code on 140 other js files.

How can I make something shared between these files.

So that I have a base kllas with seft.city and self.inputnumeric so no need to copy paste the code on 140 files

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review. You could have a look at [codereview.se], but be sure to check out [their FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because your question currently has some issues that makes it likely that they will close it too (for other reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GlobalModule function , a separate Js file and put in all the function in there.

Then first reference GlobalModule File and Start using it Like

GlobalModule.getCity();

Another thing that i would like to point , if you are using Knockout then you should consider using Jquery as little as possible.

As per Code snippet above , You could have used "attr" binding to change the Css as per the need.

This would make Code more clean and help improve maintenance as well.